# auto_start error in ld86 compiling

Tags: linux, bcc-compiler

I'm trying to compile a fairly basic program under Linux and I'm having trouble with `ld86`. Anyone have an idea as to what `auto_start` is?

```
$ bcc  -c tc.c
$ as86 -o ts.o ts.s
$ ld86 -d ts.o tc.o /usr/lib/bcc/libc.a
ld86: warning: _gets redefined in file /usr/lib/bcc/libc.a(gets.o); using definition in tc.o
undefined symbol: auto_start
```

UPDATE 3/12/2012: Seems to go away when I define my own `printf()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huzzah! I have found it.

When calling main() in main.c I was using parameters like this

```
int main(int i, char **c)
```

However, if I use no parameters... it goes away

```
int main()
```

Must be because I do not pass anything into main from assembly. Also printf() has nothing to do with it, must have been playing with too many things at once.